# How to freeze a page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that lets users select and crop a part of a page to take a screenshot, but sometimes popups can destroy my screenshot or sometimes I want to capture something in that exact moment before it changes, so I need to freeze that page, is that possible in javascript to freeze the page completely?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the inspect mode of chrome and right click on the element in the DOM. There you can add a stoping by changing of the element.

[Chrome Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAqxc.png)

Comment: hey, thanks but I think I'm going to take a full-page screenshot before letting the user select and crop from that image directly